# Build AOSP kernel, where to locate build errors

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, android-source

I just made this test driver using AOSP kernel "https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common"

I put my driver code "tdrive", under "common/drivers", in which contains 2 files "Makefile" and "hello_kernel.c"

I also added my module in the common/drivers/Makefile as obj-y

After I type "./build/build.sh"

I got build error as

```
make: *** [/work/android/aosp/repo-db845c/common/Makefile:185: __sub-make] Error 2
```

Nothing else for the error, I have no clue but open the makefile mentioned above, at the line 185 it looks like:

```
 183 # Invoke a second make in the output directory, passing relevant variables
 184 __sub-make:
 185         $(Q)$(MAKE) -C $(abs_objtree) -f $(abs_srctree)/Makefile $(MAKECMDGOALS)
```

Anyone can tell where should I go to find my errors? Thanks!

PS -  I also tried with

```
./build/build.sh -d
```

Comment: make should print what it is doing.  What happens when you run the code from line 185 manually?

Comment: Thanks Stark, I have no idea how to run the 'make' manually, all I know is just eexecute './build/build.sh'

Do you have any advise on "how to run the make manually"?

Comment: Does it not print the lines as it runs?  You just want to see the line that fails.  Like:  make __sub-make

Comment: You did something wrong in your code in case it compiles without your stuff. So, without seeing what is in your *Makefile* it's hard to tell anything. Also note, if you run parallel make the last error can be not the real error that occurred.

Comment: Hi Stark, Andriy, thanks for your patient and prompt replies.

I have fixed my problem, but sorry I didn't make notes.

My makefile and driver code is simply define a c source code, it was fine.

The problem I thinkg was missing of "source drivers/tdrive/Kconfig" in the file "drivers/Kconfig" after I have added "obj-y += tdrive" in "drivers/Makefile"

Does it make sense?